# Need to read string from file to array

Tags: pascal

I need to read lines from file. File looks like this:

```
5
Juozas tumas     6 7 8 9 7
Andrius rapšys   2 9 8 7 1
petras balvonas  1 1 1 2 3 
Daiva petronyte  8 9 7 8 4
Julia bertulienė 10 10 10 5 1
```

When I try to read it, I get the error "overload".

Here's my code:

```
 WriteLn('Hi,press ENTER!');
  Assign(x,'D:/Duomenys.txt');
  reset(x);
  readln(x,k);

  for i := 0 to k do
  begin
      read(x,c[i],d[i]);
  end;

  close(x);
  Readln;
```

Comment: In order to get good responses, here are a few things to keep in mind. 1) Assume you'll need to write all the code yourself. We'll generally only point you in the right direction. 2) What Have You Tried? (Google that phrase). We need to see your attempts at solving this. 3) Make sure you've thoroughly checked documentation and a search engine. If someone else finds the answer that way, you'll get a curt "RTD" or "LMGTFY" and a LOT of downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually parse the strings. Otherwise the input will not work. Analyze and try this code.

```
type
  TMyRec = record //each line of your text file contains alike set of data
    Name1, Name2: string;
    Numbers: array [1 .. 5] of word;
  end;

var
  x: text;
  tmps, s: string;
  SpacePos: word;
  RecArray: array of TMyRec;
  i: byte;

procedure DeleteSpacesAtBeginning(var str: string);
//code will delete spaces before the processed string
begin
  repeat
    if pos(' ', str) = 1 then //if the first char in string is ' '
      Delete(str, 1, 1);
  until pos(' ', str) <> 1;
end;

begin
  WriteLn('Hi,press ENTER!');
  Assign(x, 'd:\Duomenys.txt');
  reset(x);
  readln(x, s); // actually, you don't need any counter. Use eof instead;
  SetLength(RecArray, 0);//clear the dynamic array
  while not eof(x) do
  begin
    SetLength(RecArray, Length(RecArray) + 1);
    //append one empty record to the dynamic array
    readln(x, s);
    WriteLn(s); //if you really need it
    SpacePos := pos(' ', s); //finds the first space position
    RecArray[High(RecArray)].Name1 := Copy(s, 1, SpacePos - 1); 
    //copies substring from the string
    Delete(s, 1, SpacePos); //deletes the substring and space after it

    DeleteSpacesAtBeginning(s);
    SpacePos := pos(' ', s);
    RecArray[High(RecArray)].Name2 := Copy(s, 1, SpacePos - 1);
    //assignes the last name
    Delete(s, 1, SpacePos);

    for i := 1 to 4 do //4 because the 5th does not have space char after it
    //may be 5 if you have ' ' before the line break
    begin
      DeleteSpacesAtBeginning(s);
      SpacePos := pos(' ', s);
      tmps := Copy(s, 1, SpacePos - 1);
      RecArray[High(RecArray)].Numbers[i] := StrToInt(tmps);
      Delete(s, 1, SpacePos);
    end;
    DeleteSpacesAtBeginning(s); //now we assign the 5th number
    RecArray[High(RecArray)].Numbers[5] := StrToInt(s);

  end; //repeat the code until all the file si not read to the end
  sleep(1000);
  readln;
  //do anything you want with the processed data stored in the array
end.
```